# Search if a sub-string is in a list, as well as finding the index of every occurrence in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make a simple search engine that searches a list given in the parameter(list1) by the term listed in the parameter(search). I've gotten the list and search term to change to lowercase, and I've gotten it to recognize when it sees a match. However I can't seem to get the index of every instance

```
def search_results(list1,search):
    list2lower = [element.lower() for element in list1]
    searchlower = search.lower()
    newlist = []

    for text in list2lower:
        if search.lower() in text:
            item = list2lower.index(search)
            newlist.append(list1[item])
    print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I'm sure it can be done A LOT cleaner than this but it works for what I need. Feel free to look at the full cluster of wtf at https://repl.it/@tyrantosaurusex/Project-4

```
def search_results(list1,search):
    list2lower = [element.lower() for element in list1]
    searchlower = search.lower()
    item = [i for i,s in enumerate(list2lower) if searchlower 
    in s]
    result = any(searchlower in word for word in list2lower)

    while len(search) > 0:
        while result is True:
            for sam in item:
                print(list1[sam])

            list2lower = [element.lower() for element in 
            list1]
            search = input('Enter search query (blank to 
            exit): ')
            searchlower = search.lower()
            item = [i for i, s in enumerate(list2lower) if 
            searchlower in s]
            result = any(searchlower in word for word in 
            list2lower)
            if len(search) == 0:
                break

list_of_items = ['Keanu', 'Stamos', 'Goldblum', 'Gosling']

search_results(list_of_items,'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the smaller-case version of `search`. Instead of

```
item = list2lower.index(search)
```

Use:

```
item = list2lower.index(searchlower)
```

Here's the rewritten code:

```
def search_results(list1, search):
    list2lower = [element.lower() for element in list1]
    searchlower = search.lower()
    newlist = []

    for text in list2lower:
        if searchlower in text:
            item = list2lower.index(searchlower )
            newlist.append(list1[item])
    print(newlist)
```